# Break a foreach loop

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am working on a windows phone project in c#. In the game you need to get the red point inside your "Player"/ellipse. You can control the player with the accelerometer sensor.

When the red dot is inside you, a counter begins to count. This works only for the first ellipse. This ellipse is also declared as the first ellipse in the XAML file.

When the first red dot is inside the player, the if statement is called. But when the player is on the second red dot, the loop is jumping between the if and the else statement but I don't know why he is doing this...

edit: 
the problem is that when I have a intersection with one dot I will start to count, but because of it's inside a foreach loop it will loop trough it 5 times
so
dot1 no intersection so goes to else and reset the counter to 0
dot2 no intersection so goes to else and reset the counter to 0
dot3 no intersection so goes to else and reset the counter to 0
dot4 no intersection so goes to else and reset the counter to 0
dot5 has a intersection so it starts to count.

but it loops again because it is in a timer so it automatically sets counter to 0

anybody know why this is happening?

```
foreach (Ellipse mellipse in mCanvas.Children.OfType<Ellipse>())
{
    if (mellipse.Name != "my_ellipse")
    {
        int ellipse_top = (int)my_ellipse.Margin.Top;
        int ellipse_left = (int)my_ellipse.Margin.Left;

        if (Canvas.GetLeft(mellipse) >= ellipse_left && Canvas.GetLeft(mellipse) + mellipse.Width <= ellipse_left + my_ellipse.Width && Canvas.GetTop(mellipse) >= ellipse_top && Canvas.GetTop(mellipse) + mellipse.Height <= ellipse_top + my_ellipse.Height)
        {
            my_ellipse.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGreen);
            count++;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(mellipse.Name);
            //if (count == 100)
            //{
            //    mellipse.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            //    break;
            //}
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            my_ellipse.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            count = 0;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("else");
        }
    }
}
```

[code]

```
<Canvas Name="mCanvas">
        <Ellipse Name="my_ellipse" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="White" Width="100"/>

        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="140,106,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Canvas.Left="44" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" Canvas.Top="44" Foreground="#FF232020" FontSize="18.667"/>
        <Ellipse Name="_1" Fill="Red" Height="39" Canvas.Left="248" Stroke="Indigo" Canvas.Top="187" Width="39"/>
        <Ellipse Name="_2" Fill="Red" Height="39" Canvas.Left="185" Stroke="Indigo" Canvas.Top="390" Width="39"/>
        <Ellipse Name="_3" Fill="Red" Height="39" Canvas.Left="146" Stroke="Indigo" Canvas.Top="614" Width="39"/>
        <Ellipse Name="_4" Fill="Red" Height="39" Canvas.Left="316" Stroke="Indigo" Canvas.Top="509" Width="39"/>
    </Canvas>
```

[/code]

[Game_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrygR.png)
[XAML layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BE25O.png)

Comment: What process is actually running the loop?

Comment: the loop is  running in a timer

Comment: Your title, "Windows phone c# foreach loop wrong?" is very vague. You should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33897660/edit) it to be more descriptive. Also have a look at ["*Should questions include “tags” in their titles?*"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/284827) where the consensus is "no - titles should not contain tags".

Comment: You should try setting a breakpoint on the `if` statement and inspect the value of the variables to understand what's going on. Alternatively, you can display their value in the console by using `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(...)`

Comment: @WaiHaLee you edited but left the title alone :/

Comment: @Will - I didn't really know *what* to change it to. I assumed that the unique title rule would prevent me from editing the title to "foreach loop wrong?" - even if I did, it's not a good title...